# Ошибка H10 при развёртывании telegram бота написанного на python на сервере heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

пытаюсь залить python бота на heroku, не получается. При попытке залить бата на сервер heroku в логах вылетает это:

```
2021-08-03T12:23:15.808911+00:00 app[web.1]: raise BadRequest(message)
2021-08-03T12:23:15.808949+00:00 app[web.1]: telegram.error.BadRequest: Bad webhook: ip 
address 0.0.0.0 is reserved
2021-08-03T12:23:16.790738+00:00 app[web.1]: stopping due to exception in another thread
2021-08-03T12:24:12.038447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed 
to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of 
launch
2021-08-03T12:24:12.136528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-08-03T12:24:12.225643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-08-03T12:24:13.022678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-03T12:31:50.775981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" 
method=GET path="/" host=onlyorganizerbot.herokuapp.com request_id=6f23fdfe-72e1-4768-b9eb- 
77f7ecce2673 fwd="34.207.234.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

В Procfile написано следующее:

```
web: python3 main.py
```

Подскажите как её исправить? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать `worker: python3 main.py`, вместо `web: python3 main.py` в Procfile.

Из официальной документации Heroku -

> Web: Web dynos are dynos of the “web” process type that is defined in your Procfile. Only web dynos receive HTTP traffic from the routers. Worker: Worker dynos can be of any process type declared in your Procfile, other than “web”. Worker dynos are typically used for background jobs, queueing systems, and timed jobs.

Heroku пытается найти и подключить веб-приложение, которое будет слушать http запросы, поступающие на сервер, найти не получается, появляется ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо большоё, помогло!)